R - add column to dataset with number of times that a row value is repeated
i've searching for how to do this in R, but unfortunately didn't found an easy way to do it.
if i have a dataset called people like this



A
B




John
Student


John
Student


John
Student


Sarah
Student


Sarah
Student


Mickey
Student



i want to add a column in that dataset that reflect the number of times the values on A column are repeated. For example an output like this



A
B
C




John
Student
3


John
Student
3


John
Student
3


Sarah
Student
2


Sarah
Student
2


Mickey
Student
1



Please! any help are very welcome!
I've tried without success the following code
people <-aggregate(people$A, people, lengths)

the output of this, is a new column x on people but all values are 1 for each row

Data in reproducible format
people <- structure(list(A = c("John", "John", "John", "Sarah", "Sarah", 
"Mickey"), B = c("Student", "Student", "Student", "Student", 
"Student", "Student")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))


Use ave instead of aggregate if you want the output vector to match the length of the grouping variable:
people$C <- as.numeric(ave(people$A, people$A, FUN = length))

people
#>        A       B C
#> 1   John Student 3
#> 2   John Student 3
#> 3   John Student 3
#> 4  Sarah Student 2
#> 5  Sarah Student 2
#> 6 Mickey Student 1

Or use run length encoding (rle) and rep
people$C <- with(rle(people$A), rep(lengths, lengths))

people
#>        A       B C
#> 1   John Student 3
#> 2   John Student 3
#> 3   John Student 3
#> 4  Sarah Student 2
#> 5  Sarah Student 2
#> 6 Mickey Student 1

Or use n() in dplyr whilst using A as the grouping variable.
library(dplyr)

people %>% mutate(C = n(), .by = A)
#>        A       B C
#> 1   John Student 3
#> 2   John Student 3
#> 3   John Student 3
#> 4  Sarah Student 2
#> 5  Sarah Student 2
#> 6 Mickey Student 1


Using split and unsplit
transform(people, C = unsplit(lapply(split(people, ~ A), nrow), A))
       A       B C
1   John Student 3
2   John Student 3
3   John Student 3
4  Sarah Student 2
5  Sarah Student 2
6 Mickey Student 1

If you have to use it, "rescuing" aggregate with unnest
library(tidyr)

aggregate(cbind(C = people$A), people, \(x) rep(length(x), length(x))) |>
  unnest(C)
# A tibble: 6 × 3
  A      B           C
  <chr>  <chr>   <int>
1 John   Student     3
2 John   Student     3
3 John   Student     3
4 Mickey Student     1
5 Sarah  Student     2
6 Sarah  Student     2

or base R
transform(people, C = unlist(aggregate(cbind(C = A), people, \(x) 
                        setNames(rep(length(x), length(x)), x))$C)[A])
       A       B C
1   John Student 3
2   John Student 3
3   John Student 3
4  Sarah Student 2
5  Sarah Student 2
6 Mickey Student 1

